# Создания консольного калькулятора на C#

Tags: c#, массивы, циклы, методы, калькулятор

Здраствуйте, суть вопроса такова - Не понимаю почему в результате умножения получается 0:

```csharp
public void Multiply()
{
    double[] numbers = new double[9999999];
    double res = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a number : ");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        Double.TryParse(a, out numbers[i]);
        res *= numbers[i];
        if (a == "quit")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"result is {res}");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Я сделал такой же код для добавления, только в переменной res я записал 0.0, но он работал правильно.
Объясните пожалуйста в чем ошибка :D

Answer (score 2):

Потому что если в `a` не число, то в `numbers[i]` оказывается ноль.

```
   if (Double.TryParse(a, out numbers[i]))
       res *= numbers[i];
```

Comment: И это случается каждый раз, когда автор хочет выйти из программы :)

Answer (score 2):

Ответ от @Igor безусловно правильный, я только добавлю, что если ещё убрать всё лишее не меняя поведения метода, то код получится такой:

```csharp
public void Multiply()
{
    double res = 1.0;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Please Enter a number : ");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        if (double.TryParse(a, out double number))
        {
            res *= number;
        }
        else if (a == "quit")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"result is {res}");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Этот код будет потреблять примерно в 9999999 раз меньше памяти.

Comment: `else if` *(6 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor спасибо, готово :)